# colour of geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble controlling the colour of barplots in ggplot

```
require(mice)
require(ggplot2)
impute <- mice(nhanes, seed = 101)
ldt <-complete(impute,"long", include=TRUE)
ldt$Imputed<-ifelse(ldt$".imp"==0,"Observed","Imputed")

ggplot(ldt[!is.na(ldt$hyp),], aes(x= factor(hyp), colour=Imputed)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~.imp, nrow = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

Which gives:
[image]

But I would like the bars to be filled with the colour, so I tried:

```
ggplot(ldt[!is.na(ldt$hyp),], aes(x= factor(hyp))) + 
  geom_bar(colour = Imputed) + 
  facet_wrap(~.imp, nrow = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

But this gives the error:

```
Error in do.call("layer", list(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat,  : 
  object 'Imputed' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fill=Imputed` instead of `colour=Imputed` in your first attempt.

```
ggplot(ldt[!is.na(ldt$hyp),], aes(x= factor(hyp), fill=Imputed)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~.imp, nrow = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

You could set `fill=Imputed` in `geom_bar` instead, but you'd have to wrap it in a call to `aes`, as you would in the call to `ggplot`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `colour = Imputed` in the original aesthetic mapping, use `fill = Imputed`

```
ggplot(ldt[!is.na(ldt$hyp),], aes(x= factor(hyp), fill=Imputed)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~.imp, nrow = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```